# Recommended placement and routing of an RC Low pass filter

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, low-pass

What are the recommended placement and routing techniques for the following RC low pass filter circuit:

[image: RC LPF SCH]

I made an initial placement and routing that's shown below:

[image: RC LPF PCB]

Actually it's randomly placed and routed because I don't have any recommendations.

Thanks.

**Edit #1:**

Thanks all, since no performance matters, I made a cleaner layout based on your suggestions that will also match the schematic placement:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For frequencies this low placement doesn't really matter. Switching R6 and C7 will make the layout somewhat cleaner though.

Answer (score 5):

1 kΩ and 12 µF give you a cutoff frequency of 13 Hz, and like *s3c* says then layout is not critical.

I would rotate R6 180°.